# What is this function aimed to do?

Tags: functions, function-construction

Table[Sum[tmatrix[[i, j]], {i, 1, 2}], {j, 1, 2}]

apparently creates some sort of a table, and it evidently works on a matrix....although it is hard for me to understand what should it do beyond that.

Comment: Isnt this a forum for mathematica questions? Clearly I misinterpreted something..

Comment: Table: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html?q=Table
Sum: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html?q=Sum

Comment: I know it's  a table, but what does this function DO.

Comment: @Bak1139 It is certainly a site for _Mathematica_ questions, but since you mentioned "misinterpreting something", let me clarify what you might have missed — Please read this first: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Specifically, your question is lacking in 1) a clear description of what exactly your problem is 2) a minimal working code example of your problem (your code doesn't run because `tmatrix` isn't defined) 3) formatted with Ctrl+K (not formatted, but this is comparatively minor) 4) some proof of a minimal Mathematica knowledge

Comment: @R.M. Proof of mathemtica knowledge: beginner at best. If this is your prerequisite I demand to be deleted asap.

Comment: Help us help you; why not mention where you saw this, if you did not come up with it yourself?

Comment: These are exam example questions

Comment: My guess is that you know what `Table` and `Sum` do independently, but aren't sure what this line of code does, correct? If so, then what you should do is to break it down and test it in parts. What does `Sum[tmatrix[[i,j]], {i, 1, 2}]` give for `j = 1`? What about `j = 2`? Now evaluate your original expression —  what do you get? If this is still complex, try looking at `tmatrix[[1, 1]]`, `tmatritx[[2, 1]]`. What do you get when you add them together? Now what do you get if you do `Sum[tmatrix[[i, 1]], {i, 1, 2}]`? And so on... use a pencil and paper if necessary.

Comment: Okay, try running `tmatrix = Array[C, {2, 2}]` before running the code snippet you have. Note what you get.

Comment: @R.M. No I don't need a pen and paper thank you very much for your honest (?) but certainly condescending attitude...

Comment: It wasn't meant to be condescending... I was only trying to help you break it down (since a blanket "break it into smaller parts" by itself won't help if you don't know what the "parts" are). There is no shame in using a pencil and paper, unless that's somehow demeaning to you or is an insult to your abilities. I still use a pencil and paper everyday for solving/working through problems that I find difficult (including code) and I don't see this as a particularly bad suggestion for someone who is a self described "beginner at best". Checking the ego at the door is the first step to learning ;)

Comment: FWIW, sometimes pen + paper teaches things that coding cannot. We're trying to help you here, and if we really wanted to be arses to people, there are other places for that. The 'tude will certainly not help you learn faster.

Answer (score 2):

To see what it "does", use symbolic values as suggested by J.M.

```
(tmatrix = Array[t, {2, 2}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
(expr1 = Table[Sum[tmatrix[[i, j]], {i, 1, 2}], {j, 1, 2}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

An alternate way to obtain this result

```
expr1 === Plus @@@ Transpose[tmatrix]

(*  True  *)
```